# How to write a test for conditional rendering component depended on useState hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-redux, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to write a test for my functional component, but don't understand how to mock `isRoomsLoaded` to be `true`, so I could properly test my UI. How and what do I need to mock?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRooms } from '../../store/roomsStore';  // Action creator


// Rooms component
export default ({ match, location, history }) => {
    const roomsStore = useSelector(state => state.rooms);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isRoomsLoaded, setRoomsLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const asyncDispatch = async () => {
            await dispatch(fetchRooms());
            setRoomsLoaded(true);  // When data have been fetched -> render UI
        };
        asyncDispatch();
    }, [dispatch]);

    return isRoomsLoaded
        ? <RoomsList />  // Abstraction for UI that I want to test
        : <LoadingSpinner />;

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you could flat out mock `useState` to just return true or false, to get whichever result you want by doing the following.

```
const mockSetState = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useState: value => [true, mockSetState],
}));
```

By doing this, you're effective mocking react, with react, except useState, its a bit hacky but it'll work.